# 2 div boxes side by side with 50% width and 100% height, expanding to 100% fill up the whole width on hover on each box

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to have 2 div boxes with 50% width each and 100% height.. and within that div box, it is like an anchor link where we hover the mouse over the 1st box (Box A), Box A will transition from its 50% width to full 100% width from left to right. And if we were to hover the mouse over on Box B, it would also transition from right to left and fill up the width 100%.

Maybe a picture can explain better.. This is the initial state:
[image: Initial State (without hover)]

Then when the mouse hovers over Box A on the left:
[image: box a with hover]

Then when the mouse hovers over Box B on the right:
[image: Box b with hover]

I am unsure how to do this with CSS or with javascript/jquery or with both? I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Thanks :)

Comment: @krizalis, Please, take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/tbegh1am/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CSS, you can do somthing like this :

```
.container .box_A,
.container .box_B {
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}
.container:hover .box_A ,
.container:hover .box_B {
    width: 0%;
}
.container:hover .box_A:hover ,
.container:hover .box_B:hover {
    width: 100%;
}
```

For HTML like this :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box_A"></div>
    <div class="box_B"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: im accepting this as the answer because ive tested it and it works for my use case.. i've also created a jsfiddle demo in case anyone wants to see how it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/7whv1xn7/6/

Answer (score 5):

Here is a method using flexbox.

To allow the hover effect to work on the previous sibling I've reversed the order in the HTML.  There may be a simpler way to do this but I couldn't crack it..

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  /* below is styling for demo */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.b {
  order: 2;
}

.block:hover {
  min-width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.block:first-of-type:hover+.block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block b">B</div>
  <div class="block a">A</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Flexbox can do anything (almost):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,html {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  border: 7px solid #999;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
}
.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.left:hover, .right:hover {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.right {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

with some jquery

```js
$(".a").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".a").css("width" , "100%");
    $(".b").css("width" , "0");
});
$(".b").on("mouseover", function () {
    $(".b").css("width" , "100%");
    $(".a").css("width" , "0");
});
$(".a").on("mouseout", function () {
    $(".a").css("width" , "50%");
    $(".b").css("width" , "50%");
});
$(".b").on("mouseout", function () {
    $(".a").css("width" , "50%");
    $(".b").css("width" , "50%");
});
```

```css
body, html {height:100%; margin:0;}
.a {
  background-color:red;
  width:50%; height:100%;
  float:left;
  transition: all .3s;
  }
.b {
  background-color:blue;
  width:50%; height:100%;
  float:left;
  transition: all .3s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS like this:

```
.parent {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 3em;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
}

.left {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.left:hover {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.right {
 background: blue;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 50%;
 z-index: 1;
 transition: width 1s;
}

.right:hover {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Made a fiddle to illustrate example: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk8bctkv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For CSS like this :

```css
 .ParentDiv{
     border:1px solid #000;
     height:200px;
     width:300px;
     margin:0 auto;
     position: relative;
    }

    .Box_A {
        width:50%;
     height:100%;
        text-align:center;
     left:0;
        background: #ff3232;
        transition:all 2s ease;
     position: absolute;
    }

    .Box_A:hover {
     width:100%;
     background: #fff;
     z-index: 2;
     display:block;
    }

    .Box_A > a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .Box_B {
        width:50%;
     height:100%;
        text-align:center;
     right:0;
        background: #ff3232;
        transition:all 2s ease;
     position: absolute;
     border-left:1px solid gray;
    }

    .Box_B:hover {
     width:100%;
     background: #fff;
     z-index: 2;
     display:block;
    }

    .Box_B > a {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="ParentDiv">
 <div class="Box_A"><a href="">Box A</a></div>
 <div class="Box_B"><a href="">Box B</a></div>
</div>

<!--End ParentDiv-->
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class = "left" id = "left">
    </div>
    <div class = "right" id = "right">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body    {
    background-color: #ffeead;
}

.left:hover,
.right:hover{
    width: 60%;
}

.left:hover ~ #right {
    width: 40%;
}

.left {
  background-color: #ff6f69;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.right {
  background-color: #ffeead;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```